# UITableView left gap

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

When setting up the UITableView in IB, it looks like this:
[image]

But when i build the project, there is a gap, like this:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is the iOS 7 `separatorInset` in action. It is a stylistic change but also determines the default offset of the built-in `UITableViewCell` subviews. You should be able to change this in your storyboard or do it in code by using something like:

```
self.tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
```

As a side note you can more finely tune this behavior using the same property on `UITableViewCell` to change the inset for just a single cell (or a single type of cell).

These properties are available in iOS 7+ only so if you support a lower version of iOS you'll need to account for that by doing something like:

```
if([self.tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) 
{ 
  self.tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero; 
}
```

*edited: updated answer with comment from @pawan*

Comment: So simple, yet so hard to figure out, if you didn't know... Thanks!

Comment: if ([self.tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [self.tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    } for making not to crash in ios 6.0.